# How can I dynamically change an object that is set in another file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, object, dynamic, node-modules

I have a problem and need your help. I am currently working on a project in which I have to save a **javascript object** in an external file and export the whole thing via **module.exports**.

Now to my problem and I would now like that another file changes a certain value in my object. This is also possible with:

```
OBJECT.VALUE = "YOUR NEW VALUE"
```

Problem is that it now works in this session but the object should permanently change this value means Node.js now has to change this value in the object file too.

I guess I have to use the **fs library** but I don't know how exactly? I would like to keep the structure of the object means the script should only change the value

***Here you have the Object File:***

```
const Core = new Object();

Core['config'] = {

    ['test'] : "Test"

}

// Export the Core
module.exports.Core = Core;
```

***What i tried in other File:***

```
const { Core } = require('./settings/Core.js')


Core['config']['test'] = "MY NEW VALUE"
```

Comment: what is `a javascript object in an external file`, Is it JSON ?  `export the whole thing via module.exports.` You can read the file once you update the file.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways you could go about this.

Create a getter and setter function in your object file and export them.

```
function setObject(field, newVal){ 
  Core.config[field] = newVal
}

function getObject(){
  return Core;
}


module.exports = {setObject, getObject}
```

In your other file call the function.

```
const {setObject, getObject } = require('./settings/Core.js')
```

Now just use the functions to retrieve or update the object

```
setObject("Test", "NewValue")
```